# Spring Boot REST Api JWT AuthorizationFilter does not validate the token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I am made a sample spring boot app implementing JWT token authentication which is working partially. That means it does not let the request access the endpoints until generating the token by sending user details using /login url. Once the token is received, the token is sent with a header called Authorization. So untill the first url all with this header, it does not allow to access endpoints. But after the 1st call I can access the enpoints without the Authorization header which contains the JWT token.

SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
    this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    System.out.println("from SecurityConfig constructor");
    System.out.println(this.customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("batman").getUsername());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("from configure");
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()

    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/sign_up").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/*/floor1/**").hasRole("USER")
    .antMatchers("/*/floor2/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .and()
    .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), customUserDetailsService));
    }


}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    // {"username":"batman","password":"123"}
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        System.out.println(">>>>> AuthenticationFilter: checking user credentials....");
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(applicationUser.getUsername(), applicationUser.getPassword()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(">>>>> AuthenticationFilter: error in checking user credentials....");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(">>>>> AuthenticationFilter: error in checking user credentials....");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println(">>>>> AuthenticationFilter: successfulAuthentication creating token...");
    ZonedDateTime expirationTimeUTC = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).plus(SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(((User)authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
        .setExpiration(Date.from(expirationTimeUTC.toInstant()))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SecurityConstants.SECRET)
        .compact();
    response.getWriter().write(token);
    response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    System.out.println(">>>>> AuthenticationFilter: successfulAuthentication token created and added to response");
    }

}
```

JwtAuthorizationFilter.java

```
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


    public JwtAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
    super(authenticationManager);
    this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
    System.out.println(">>>>> AuthorizationFilter doFilterInternal: checking the availability of toke header...");
    if(header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)){
        System.out.println(">>>>> AuthorizationFilter doFilterInternal: header is null or not start with token prefix");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthenticationToken(request);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println(">>>>> AuthorizationFilter UsernamePasswordAuthentication: validating the token...");
    String token = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
    if(token == null){
        System.out.println(">>>>> AuthorizationFilter UsernamePasswordAuthentication: error: token is null");
        return null;
    }
    String username = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SecurityConstants.SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getBody().getSubject();
    UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    ApplicationUser applicationUser = customUserDetailsService.loadApplicationUserByUsername(username);
    return username != null ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(applicationUser, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()) : null;
    }


}
```

in JwtAuthorizationFilter.java it returns true where the token is check for null. So it is supposed to prevent accessing endpoints
and give an error to the client. But it does not. It allows the request to slip through the filter
and access the endpoint. Please help me if i am missing something here.

Complete sample project: https://github.com/xandar6/jwt

Comment: What is the point of using two auth filters here?

Comment: one is to authentica the user by validating username and password. other one to validate the token